# If 51 mosquitoes are sitting on a square with side 1m, are at least 3 of them within a disk of radius 1/7?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, pigeonhole-principle

> There are 51 mosquitoes on a square-shaped window with side 1 m. Can
>   Stephen kill 3 mosquitoes with a circular plastic disk of radius 1/7 m
>   in a single strike?

I know this can be solved by applying Dirichlet principle, but can't put whole proof together - I can't focus, since my room is full of mosquitoes. ;)

Comment: Am I missing something? Of course he can kill 3 mosquitoes if they happen to be in the radius of his disk! Is the question relating to the likelihood of killing 3 mosquitoes in a single strike?

Comment: @StretchManiac Will Stephen be able to kill 3 mosquitoes in a single strike, no mater how mosquitoes are distributed on the window? (also, disk = circular surface)

Comment: The problem is, mosquitoes are not discrete. In other words, you have not defined how close together the mosquitoes can be, and I assume right now that they are points that can all share the same location. In that way, unless the disk is the shape and size of the window, there will always be an escape for all of the mosquitoes, being that they can all occupy a single point.

Comment: It is assumed that Stephen is intelligent and capable, so he would kill all of them in a single strike for the case you described @StretchManiac

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. You might want to include that Stephen is an intelligent individual who will actively hunt mosquitoes in your question. I got the impression that he was random.

Comment: Can you assume the mosquitos are not points - that is occupy a finite, nonzero volume? Furthermore, are these female or male mosquitos - the sizes are quite different, and from my preliminary calculations, could end up mattering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the square into $5 \times 5$ squares of side $0.2$m.  The diagonal of each square is $\frac {\sqrt 2}5 \lt \frac 27$, so each square can be covered by a disk of radius $\frac 17$  Two mosquitoes per square is $50$, there must be a third one in a square so squash that square.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!